# Не могу установить mod_wsgi

Tags: python, windows, pip, mod-wsgi

```
Windows 10

Apache24

Python 3.8.1
```

задаю команду `pip install mod_wsgi`

Была ошибка, что не находит Visual C++ 14.00, после установки Visual Studio удалось от нее избавиться.

Теперь появляется ошибка, что не находит файл `ws2tcpip.h`
Эту ошибку устранить никак не получается.

Вот скриншот ошибки:
[image: Ошибка]

Как мне избавиться от этой ошибки и установить `mod_wsgi`?

Comment: А вам так принципиально на Windows разворачивать весь стак? Там будут еще зависимости, если система у вас чистая. Попробуйте развернуть в виртуальной машине под каким нибудь GNU/Linux. На Fedora или Debian проблем не возникнет. В вашем случае нужно будет каждый разд доустоваливать зависимости сборки каждого пакета. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ws2tcpip/

Comment: `mod_wsgi` можно скачать и установить уже собранный, [отсюда](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mod_wsgi). Только выбери правильный файл (если у тебя 32-битный питон версии 3.8, то тебе нужен `mod_wsgi‑4.7.1+ap24vc15‑cp38‑cp38‑win32.whl`, а если 64-битный, то `mod_wsgi‑4.7.1+ap24vc15‑cp38‑cp38‑win_amd64.whl` и т.д.)